# Proving that if every infinite subset of a metric space has a limit point then the metric space is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

If $X$ is a metric space such that every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point. Prove that $X$ is compact.

Proof: I'll try to use hint given in Ex-2.26 of Rudin's Principals of Mathematical analysis. 
Suppose on the contrary that $X$ is not compact and therefore $\exists$ an open cover of $X$ (let's call it $S$) without a finite subcover. As per our assumption, no finite sub collection of $G_i's$ can cover $X$.
Since $X$ is separable, it must have a countable base $\implies $ every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover. Let $\{G_n\}$ be such countable subcover. 
We define $F_i=\text{complement of} \cup_{j=1}^{j=i}G_j=\cap_{j=1}^{j=i}G_j^c$ 
We have, $X\subseteq \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}G_j\implies X\cap (\cap_{j=1}^{\infty}G_j^c)=X\cap (\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i)=\phi\tag{1}$ 
We form an *infinite set $E_1=\{x_i\}$ by taking $x_i\in F_i$ such that $x_{i+1}\in F_{i+1}-\{x_1,...,x_i\}$ for all $i$.
$E_1=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ has a limit point $c$ in $X$. Noting that $F_1\supseteq F_2\supseteq F_3\supseteq...$.
$E_n=\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$ is contained in $F_n$ for every $n.c$ is limit point of $E_n\subseteq F_n$ for every $n$ (subsequence of a convergent sequence converging to $t$ has limit $t$) and therefore $c$ is a limit point of $F_n$ also. Since $F_n$ is closed, we must have $c\in F_n$ for every $n\implies c\in \cap F_n$, which is a contradiction.

*For sake of completeness, let $E_1$ be finite and has only $k$ elements that is $F_{k+1}-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}=\phi\implies F_{k+1}^c$ has all elements of $X$ except $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$. 
$F_{k+1}^c=\cup_{i=1}^{i=k+1}G_i$. Thus we have, $X\subseteq F_{k+1}^c\cup \{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}=\cup_{i=1}^{i=k+1}G_i\cup \{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}$ 
There exist $j_1,j_2,...,j_m$ such that $x_i\in G_{j_i}$ for all $i\in \{1,2,...,m\}$.

Thus we have, $X\subseteq F_{k+1}^c\cup \{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}=\cup_{i=1}^{i=k+1}G_i\cup \{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{i=k+1}G_i\cup (\cup_{i=1}^{i=m}G_{j_i})$, which is a contradiction as $X$ can't be covered by finite no. of $G_i$'s.

Is my understanding of hints provided and hence above proof correct?

Comment: I think it's basically good, at least for the separable case. However, why can you assume that $X$ is separable?

Comment: @Berci: That's an exercise in Rudin's Principal of Mathematical analysis. In the exercise, it is to be proven that $X$ is separable if every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point.